# signalR invoke from event in server-side

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, notifications, signalr

I created an notification system in use with signalR, and also created an event that happens as soon as an notification is added. I'd like to call the function in my `notifictionHub` from the same event I've seen some solutions that are not valid for the version I'm working with, I'd like to know how can i do this?

NotificationHub:

```
        public async Task SendNotification(string user, string content)
        {
            string userID = "3";
            foreach(var cid in _connections.GetConnections(userID))
            {
                await Clients.Client(cid).SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", user, content);
            }
        }
```

Add notification event:

```
        private static void Notifications_OnNotificationAdd(Account account, Notification notification)
        {
            // call NotificationHub->SendNotification from here...  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event class:

```cs
//using this instance object, we are able to access and call the hub methods.
private IHubContext<notifictionHub> _hub;
```

In your event method:

```cs
private static void Notifications_OnNotificationAdd(Account account, Notification notification)
{
   _hub.Clients.All.SendNotification(yourUser, yourContent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, When I'm trying to do your solution i recive this error:
`
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Notifications._hub' 
`

When im trying to set it static it's null and it crash my program :( @Praetorian1995

Comment: if this does not work you can use the GlobalHost like: ```rivate static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();```

Comment: Tryed with readonly gave me the same error before, and i read about GlobalHost it's not suitable to my program because I'm using net-core.

Comment: Maybe what is missing now is the constructor.

```public yourClass(IHubContext<notificationHub> hubContext)
{
_hub = hubContext;
}
```